# Synthesize smallest map satisfying featurec constraints in core.logic?

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

In `core.logic`, is there a way to translate the outputs of a program like

```
(run 2 [q]
  (fresh [a]
    (featurec q {:foo a})
    (membero a '(5))
    (conde 
      ((featurec q {:bar 2}))
      ((featurec q {:baz 2})))))
```

into the smallest maps that satisfy each solution's constraints, in this case `{:foo 5, :bar 2}` and `{:foo 5, :baz 2}`?

Comment: Why use `featurec` when the minimal set of keys is already known? Why not `(== q {:foo a :bar 2})`?

Comment: In a more complex (potentially even recursive) relation, some `featurec` clauses might appear only in some solutions; e.g., `conde` clauses that each introduce different `featurec` constraints. I've updated the question to give an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, which is a bit complicated, but it does the job.

```
(->> (run 1 [q]
              (fresh [l1 l2 a]
                     (membero a '(5))
                     (emptyo l1)
                     (conso [:foo a] l1 l2)
                     (conso [:bar 2] l2 q)))
         (first)
         (into {}))
```

or

```
(run 1 [q]
         (fresh [a B]
                (membero a '(5))
                (== B 2)
                (== q {:foo a :bar B})))
```

I am sure that William Byrd can do better.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with (1) is that when `q` _is_ known, I want to be able to run this to pull out & constrain the relevant fields from `q` without worrying about the order in which `q` stores them (hence the map, rather than vector); and unfortunately, (2) wouldn't let me build up `featurec` constraints throughout a relation, potentially with `conde`s blocking some of them.